# Laravel Befriended revoke method not working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to remove a follower but the revokeFollower() method returns nothing and not working. Using the **Laravel Befriended** https://github.com/renoki-co/befriended package.

```
public function unfollowFollowers(Request $request){
    $loginUser = Auth::user();
    return $loginUser->revokeFollower($request['id']);
}
```

**User.php**

```
use Rennokki\Befriended\Traits\Follow;
use Rennokki\Befriended\Contracts\Following;
use Rennokki\Befriended\Scopes\FollowFilterable;

 class User extends Authenticatable implements Following  
 {
   use Notifiable,Follow,FollowFilterable;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

On the README there is mentioned:

> **Note: Following, unfollowing or checking if following models that do not correctly implement `CanBeFollowed` and `Followable` will always return `false`.**